# How does accessing a NumPy array like `arr[arr>5]` work?

Tags: python, numpy

So I'm trying to learn Numpy and I cannot understand how this block of code is giving the output it is:

```
arr = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

arr[arr>5]
```

Output :

```
array([6,7,8,9,10])
```

I do know that actually an array of boolean values is returned by `arr>5` but I just can't understand how that boolean array when passed to `arr[]` gives the specified output.
Help Appreciated.

Comment: The general answer is "that's how numpy works" https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> a
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

As you already said, `a > 5` results in an array of boolean values:

```
>>> mask = a > 5
>>> mask
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
```

This can be interpreted as a mask. Similar to the way you can access [single elements](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#single-element-indexing), for example the first element, with

```
>>> a[0]
1
```

You can access specific elements by using [index arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) through this mask:

```
>>> a[mask]
array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5` don't appear because the first 5 elements of `mask` are `False`. The rest is `True` and therefore `6, 7, 8, 9, 10` are shown.

Comment: Ohk! I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: Ok. Thank you for informing me. I'll keep that in mind.